# How to gather value(s) from check-boxes, and sync that value to a pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to grab the value from checkboxes, and sync those value into my pivot table.

I have 3 tables :

- catalog_downloads
- export_frequencies
- catalog_download_export_frequency (Pivot Table)

### Here is what I've tried

View > My check-boxes

```
    {{ Form::label('export_frequency' , 'Export Frequency', array('class'=> 'required cool-blue'))}} <br>

    @foreach (ExportFrequency::all() as $export_frequency)

    <input type="checkbox" name="{{$export_frequency->name}}" id="{{$export_frequency->id}}" value="{{$export_frequency->name}}">
    {{$export_frequency->name}} <br>

    @endforeach
```

[image]

In my Controller (CatalogDownloadController.php)

```
public function store()
    {

        $catalog_download        = new CatalogDownload;
        $catalog_download->title = Input::get('title');
        $catalog_download->save();

        foreach(ExportFrequency::all() as $export_frequency ){

            $export_frequency_id = Input::get($export_frequency->name);

            if(is_array($export_frequency_id))
            {
                $catalog_download->export_frequencies()->sync([$export_frequency_id, $catalog_download_id]);
                $catalog_download_id = $catalog_download->id;
            }
        }

        return Redirect::to('catalog_downloads/')
        ->with('success','The catalog_download was created succesfully!');

}
```

### Goal

Again, I just want to sync : $export_frequency_id, $catalog_download_id
to my `catalog_download_export_frequency` table.

### Question

Can someone tell me what I missed ? The result won't sync.
Feel free to give me suggestions/advice on this.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: haha why don't you add me in skype and I explain it to you there. that might be faster...

Comment: You got mail (at your outlook address)

Comment: I see you used my solution for relationships and your pivot table. I'll write up an answer for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it mate:

```
// Your form view
{{ Form::label('export_frequencies' , 'Export Frequencies', array('class'=> 'required cool-blue'))}} <br />
@foreach ($exportFrequencies as $exportFrequency)
    <input type="checkbox" name="export_frequencies[]" id="{{ $exportFrequency->id }}" value="{{ $exportFrequency->id }}">
    {{ $exportFrequency->name }}<br />
@endforeach

// Your store method
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::except('export_frequencies');
    $exportFrequencies = Input::get('export_frequencies'); // Use get, not only

    $catalogDownload = $this->catalogDownload->create($input); // Using dependency injection here, so don't forget to assign your CatalogDownload model to $this->catalogDownload in your contructor

    if (isset($exportFrequencies)
    {
        $catalogDownload->exportFrequencies()->attach($exportFrequencies);
    }

    return Redirect::to('catalog-downloads')->with('success', 'The Catalog Download was created successfully!');
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to do `$input = Input::except('export_frequencies');`

Comment: So you don't get the the export_frequencies array and attempt to insert it in to the CatalogDownload model, as those columns do not exist on that model.

Comment: How about this line `$catalogDownload = $this->catalogDownload->create($input);`

Comment: I'm getting somewhere. Now, I got this error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `export_frequencies_catalog_downloads` (`0`, `catalog_download_id`, `export_frequency_id`, `1`) values (Semi Annual, export_frequencies, 78, Quaterly))` - Why is that do you know ? My table(s) look like [THIS](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/EC.jpg)

Comment: Also dd() export_frequencies to see what you're getting when posting the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68981/discussion-between-evoque2015-and-gareth-daine).

Comment: The problem was my mistake in using only, instead of get on the Input class.